# jQuery Validate Plugin groups: Error message shows for last invalid field instead of first invalid field in the group

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

When using groups in the jQuery validate plugin, for some reason it always shows the error message for the last field in the group if both fields are invalid. Ideally it should show the error message for the first field in the group that's invalid.

Here's the code:

```
<form id="form1">
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Test" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And the JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form1').validate({
        messages: {
            firstName: {
                required: 'first name is required'
            },
            lastName: {
                required: 'last name is required'
            }
        },
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true
            },
            lastName: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        groups: {
            fullName: 'firstName lastName'
        }
    });
});
```

Ideally, when clicking on the submit button I'd like the following scenarios to play out:

1. Both fields are empty: "first name is required"
2. First name filled in, last name empty: "last name is required"
3. Last name filled in, first name empty: "first name is required"

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

One other item I'm also struggling with is if I use the "success" function to show a "valid" label when the user completes each field, it seems to ignore the fact that the fields are in groups. I'd like to only show the "valid" message when BOTH fields in the group are valid.

If anyone could help with either of these issues that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $('#form1').validate({
        messages: {
            firstName: {
                required: 'first name is required'
            },
            lastName: {
                required: 'last name is required'
            }
        },
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true,
                lastName: {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        },
        groups: {
            fullName: 'firstName lastName'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps with the messages - but it then breaks the rest of the behavior. If I start typing in the first name field now I get the following JS error (using Chrome): 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined - jquery.validate.js'